# Linux Mint, Os scripts wont work with multiple Python versions

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

some time ago I installed python 2.7.11 on my linux Mint. Probably i did it wrong because now i have python 2.7.6 (default for Mint 17.3) and 2.7.11. The main problem is that my scripts tries to use newer version of python because symplink is set on it, and they dont work propertly. For instance i cant install gi module for python 2.7.11 and OS requires that to run cinnamon-settings. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to specify a python version at the top of your script

```
#!/usr/bin/python {version}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: if i change from python2 to python2.7 it gives nothin.